# Scrollable element not showing a scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll

I created a `div` that I want to populate with elements in javascript. The number of elements is big so I wanted to make the `div` scrollable. I have done the following but the scroll bar does not show at all and my elements are added to the `div` but I can't scroll to see them.

```
<body>
   <div id="calendar" class="scrollable"></div>
</body>

.scrollable {
   padding-top:0.5%;
   height: 80%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

No specific things are done to the `body` of my project in CSS. Would you happen to know what is wrong?

Edit: the issue does not happen when I fix the size of `.scrollable` in px.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a snippet in your question and add a few sample items to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a height on the parent elements, in this case the body and html.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.scrollable {
   padding-top: 0.5%;
   height: 20%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This fixes the issue. Now I'm curious to understand why!

Comment: By setting a height of 100% on the parent we tell it to span the entire height of the viewport and then tell the child to take 20% of that space. Use the inspect tool and check the height of the html and body element with and without the height property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the height of .scrollable in **px** or **vh** something like this.

```css
.scrollable {
   padding-top:0.5%;
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Indeed when I make it fixed it works. But, since I want my design to easily adapt to different sizes of screens, I don't want to use a fixed size.

Comment: you can also  try vertical height (vh) rather than px  for different screen heights.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using max-height on the parent div ( div with expected scroll behavior )

```css
.scrollable {
   padding-top:0.5%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   max-height: 50px;
}

.child{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboruLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboruLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboruLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboruLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboruru</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```